# Phonegap minimal platform versions supported

Tags: android, windows-phone-7, blackberry, cordova, symbian

I have a big project going on my company where i have to develop to IOS, Android, symbian, Windows Phone and blackberry, after hearing and researching about Phonegap i'm really considering using it however i would like to know if there are and which are the existing requirements / limitations regarding developing with Phonegap for these platforms.

Is there somekind of mark of from which "generation" of mobile device Phonegap is optimal for these platforms ? Is there an optimal release of said OS for Phonegap ? Is there a feature that doesn't work on said OS version / device ?

I'm still researching this on the web but if someone here could lend me a hand on this matter it would be awesome !

PS : Seems like symbian development is based on Nokia's Web Runtime (WRT) so 
that makes it's rock-bottom Symbian S60 5th Edition and S60 3rd Ed. FP2.

PS': Blackberry seems to support 4.5 RIM till the most recent ones ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Android 2.1 - API level 7
- BlackBerry OS5 - but the browser sucks so OS6 is more realistic
- iOS currently 3.X but when we release PhoneGap
  2.0 in July that iOS version will bump to 4.2. Since over 90% of users are on iOS 5.X it isn't a big deal.

Answer (score 0):

I would rather build an HTML5 mobile site and just create a skin for each phone. This does depend largely on what you want the app to do, but a hybrid solution is going to be much less painful in the long run.