# ios deployment target vs Base SDK

Tags: ios, xcode

I have my Base SDK set to 5.1 and the Deployment Target set to 3.0, when I try to install the app it still says it requires a newer software version.  The iPhone I'm testing with has 3.0.  Should I try to back down the SDK version?

Comment: No, the problem is somewhere else.  Double check that the deployment setting on your *target* is 3.0 (If Xcode can even go back that far..)

Comment: The iOS Deployment Target is 3.0, which is the lowest XCode supports.  I created an archive and tried to install through iTunes but I get the error that it requires a newer version of iPhone software.  I'm not sure how many 3.0 devices are running around anymore so I may just bump it up to 4.1 at least.

Comment: What I'm saying is that there are two places to set it.  Make sure you are setting it on the TARGET, and not just your overall project.  With iOS 4.1 You will be able to support all devices back to the 3G era.  However, don't upgrade to 4.5 if you want to keep this support (4.5 only supports iOS 4.3 and up)

Comment: Yes, it was set on the target.  However, I found what I was looking for, I didn't even think about Phonegap being the limitation.  It only supports back to 4.x so that's my issue.   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11251106/phonegap-minimal-platform-versions-supported

Comment: Does the SDK matter?  Should I download SDK 4.3 for debugging etc?

Comment: The SDK doesn't matter.  You just need to make sure that the libraries you are using are all supported on your deployment target (all this info is in the docs, it will say available on iOS X.X and up)